# javascript closure in loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, closures

Following code is given:

```
var a = [ ], i = 0, j = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) { 

  (function(c) {
    a.push(function () { 

    console.log(c); });

  })(i);
};

for (j = 0; j < 5; j += 1) { a[j](); }
```

Why does `i` always get bigger by 1 instead of staying `5`? Hasn't the foor loop already been passed, so the `i` parameter given to the anonymous function should be `5`?

Comment: Because you are creating a new scope in each iteration, by calling a function, which captures the current value of `i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you referenced `i` from the inner closure then yes, you would see the result being 5 in all cases.  However, you pass `i` *by value* to the outer function, which is accepted as parameter `c`.  The value of `c` is then fixed to whatever `i` was *at the moment you created the inner closure.*

Consider changing the log statement:

```
console.log("c:" + c + " i:" + i);
```

You should see `c` going from 0 to 4 (inclusive) and `i` being 5 in all cases.

Comment: thanks for your answer, so i basically create for every loop an inner closure, which has access to its own i value?

Comment: @AndyB Kind of, technically you create inner closures that each have their own `c` variable, each of which is initialized to the value that `i` held when the closure was created.

Answer (score 2):

chhowie's answer is absolutely right (and I upvoted it), but I wanted to show you one more thing to help understand it.  Your inner function works similarly to a more explicit function call like this:

```
var a = [ ], i = 0, j = 0;

function pushFunc(array, c) {
    array.push(function () { 
        console.log(c); 
    });
}

for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) { 
    pushFunc(array, i);
}

for (j = 0; j < 5; j += 1) { a[j](); }
```

Which should also help you understand how `c` comes from the function argument, not from the `for` loop.  Your inner function is doing exactly the same thing as this, just without an externally declared named function.